# WHAT IS "libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so" and why is it showing up in my DEBUG folder?

Tags: c#, dll, shared-libraries, grpc

I have some files libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so and libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.so along with their .dylib files.
I do not have any GRPC.Core references in my "References" or in my packages.config. Why am I getting these files in my DEBUG folder upon rebuilding?

I want to know the reason because I am using veracode to scan my application and these files bring many many "Very high" vulnerabilities in the report. Below is the list of my current references:

```
<packages>
 <package id="Autofac" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
 <package id="Autofac.Extras.Quartz" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="AWSSDK.Core" version="3.5.3.9" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="AWSSDK.IdentityManagement" version="3.5.0.69" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="AWSSDK.SecurityToken" version="3.5.1.60" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="BouncyCastle" version="1.8.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="CsvHelper" version="15.0.4" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="DnsClient" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="ExcelDataReader" version="3.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="ExcelDataReader.DataSet" version="3.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Google.Apis" version="1.49.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1" version="1.49.0.1982" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Google.Apis.Auth" version="1.49.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Google.Apis.CloudResourceManager.v1" version="1.49.0.2205" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Google.Apis.CloudResourceManager.v2" version="1.49.0.2205" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.49.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Google.Apis.Iam.v1" version="1.49.0.2183" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Google.Protobuf" version="3.11.4" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="K4os.Compression.LZ4" version="1.1.11" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="K4os.Compression.LZ4.Streams" version="1.1.11" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="K4os.Hash.xxHash" version="1.0.6" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.11.3" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.11.3" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.11.3" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="MongoDB.Libmongocrypt" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="MySql.Data" version="8.0.22" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.3" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Npgsql" version="5.0.1.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" version="19.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Quartz" version="3.0.7" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Quartz.Serialization.Json" version="3.0.7" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="RestSharp" version="106.11.4" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="SharpCompress" version="0.23.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="SSH.NET" version="2016.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="StackExchange.Redis" version="2.2.4" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.IO.Pipelines" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.4" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Text.Json" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Threading.Channels" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Topshelf" version="4.2.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Topshelf.Autofac" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
```

Comment: You've got protobuf in there... Which leads me to believe you're using grpc somewhere

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 not necessarily, they can be used entirely separately; there is no library dependency in either direction in the .net implementation

Comment: Well ya learn something new every day. Thought one implied the other

Comment: What it *is* is the unmanaged gRPC layer (the P/Invoke C/C++ DLL that includes chttp2 etc) from the Grpc.Core package, so: assuming that when you delete the build output it keeps coming back when you build, then you have a transitive dependency to Grpc.Core somewhere. As for where: you'd need to check the dependency graph

Comment: It is the native component that's part of Grpc.Core: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/csharp#the-native-dependency  Grpc.Core is likely included as a transitive dependency. Likely it's the `Google.Apis.CloudResourceManager.v1` or other google client libraries - they depend on Grpc.Core to work.